# How to prevent abuse with AWS S3 presigned upload URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I have an API endpoint that returns an AWS S3 upload presigned URL.

Only authenticated users in my app can call this endpoint to upload music files.

However, nothing prevents a "malicious user" from creating an account and calling this endpoint an unlimited amount of times to upload an unlimited amount of files.

How can I even prevent this issue? It seems like all apps that use presigned URLs must have this issue, yet I see no questions about this, here or elsewhere

Comment: All apps that use **file uploads** have this problem!

Comment: Surely there must be a solution if this is such a common problem.

Comment: The issue that you're talking about is a moderation issue. That's a different problem than what looks like an easier problem: preventing abuse in terms of the amount of files that are uploaded. In one case you need to analyze the content of the files and in the other case, you don't care.

Comment: @MaximeDupré: are you worried about them generating lots of pre-signed URLs or using one pre-signed URL to upload lots of files?

Comment: I'm worried about them generating lots of pre-signed URLs. They could call my API endpoint and get a new pre-signed URL each time and upload many files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your application (API endpoint) will be responsible for limiting the number of calls that your users can make to that endpoint. You could set rate limiting (where the API returns an error if called too often), or return the same presigned URL until a certain amount of time passes (e.g. return only 1 URL per every X minutes per user). If you choose rate limiting, I would suggest returning a 429 error code with a `Retry-After` header to tell your caller how long to wait until the next try.

If you want to limit protect the presigned URL from misuse, I suggest you set an expiration on the URL that is limited to the typical time period that is practical for your use case. A presigned URL should be protected just like other credentials/secrets, similar to short-lived credentials from AWS STS.

If your concern is related to validating the content stored in S3 (as opposed to the API usage rate), you might consider attaching a Lambda function to the PutObject event on your S3 bucket. This Lambda could be used to perform any post-processing, triggering virus scans, file compression, etc.

If you want to optimize your storage costs in S3, consider using Intelligent Tiering on your bucket or applying a Lifecycle Policy according to your app's retention needs (move to IA after X days, Glacier after Y days, delete after Z days).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Brian. I was hoping that there was a native S3 solution to this problem, but it seems like something needs to be implemented at the app level. Your two proposed solutions to limit the number of calls seem like they would really affect the user experience negatively. I'm building a music creation website, and I don't see how I can tell a user that he can't upload 2 (or x) files back to back without waiting. And let's say I do limit the api endpoint to only 1 call every 5 minutes, someone could still upload a lot of files to my bucket in one day.

Comment: How you implement your limits is totally up to you. You can even install multiple limits, for instance 10 calls per five minutes, 1000 calls per 24 hours and 100000 total uploads per account. But in the end of the day, if you want to prevent abuse you will have to define a limit of how many uploads you want to allow. And yes, there may be some legimitate users hitting this limit too ...

Comment: @MaximeDupré - You are absolutely right. Limits always have the potential of impacting user experience. If nobody hits the limit, it won't be an issue. When someone does, it will always be an inconvenience to them. Limits represent a trade-off between the end user experience and your application's cost and stability.  Things like standard error codes and clear error messages help users to know how to respond when they hit a limit. That's typically the best way to reduce the pain so users understand what happened, how long to wait, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Throttling is a mechanism used to solve this problem.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-throttling.html) is some info on native throttling in AWS API Gateway.

However, these limits would apply to all users of an endpoint. In order to limit specific customers, you'll want to utilize [**Usage Plans**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-usage-plans.html)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, throttling is a good solution to prevent this kind of abuse.

AWS Web Application Firewall (WAF) is a great product for creating rate limit policies. For your use case it may make sense to attach WAF to a CloudFront that sits between your S3 bucket and the public internet.

You could also attach a WAF policy to a Lambda or API Gateway; CloudFront has the likely advantage of lower complexity.